# How do I load precompiled Handlebar templates with Require.js?

Tags: requirejs, handlebars.js

My precompiled template file is templates.js -- how do I load this file using RequireJS?

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery'
        , underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore'
        , handlebars: '../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars'
        , moment: '../bower_components/momentjs/moment'
        , spin: '../bower_components/spinjs/spin'
        , templates: 'templates'
    },
    shim: {
        handlebars: {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        templates: {
            deps: ['handlebars']
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["jquery", "underscore", "handlebars", "templates", "moment", "spin", "test"], function($, _, Handlebars, Templates, moment, Spinner, test) {
    test.init();
});
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237482/how-to-use-precompiled-templates-in-handlebars-with-requirejs

Answer (score 1):

You should compile your templates with [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd) support . ( I usually do it with help of [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars) [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) plugin .)

```
   requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery'
        , underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore'
        , handlebars: '../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars'
        , moment: '../bower_components/momentjs/moment'
        , spin: '../bower_components/spinjs/spin'
        , templates: 'templates'
    },
    shim: {
        handlebars: {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["jquery", "underscore", "templates", "moment", "spin", "test"]
    , function($, _, Templates, moment, Spinner, test) {
        test.init();
});
```

Now `Templates` is an object whose keys are the names of the templates and whose values are the Handlebars templating functions .

Usage example :

```
var template = Templates['templates/posts.hbs'];
document.body.innerHTML = template({
    title: 'All posts',
    posts: [
        { title: 'First post', '13/11/2013'},
        { title: 'Second post', '15/11/2013'}
    ]    
});
```